# Matlab. Using isequal for dynamic size of arrays to compare

Tags: arrays, matlab, dynamic, unique, equality

I have a dataset with many temperature profiles. Some of them are recorded in the same position and contain different data, but unfortunately sometimes there are duplicated profiles. I want to get rid of the duplicated data, without removing profiles done in the same location that are not duplicated. In order to do so I loop over every year of data and check whether the positions of all the profiles within that year are unique. Then if two or more are found in the same position I want to check whether those profiles are equal or not. The problem comes when some years there aren't any profiles in the same position, and some years there might be 2, 3 or many more. I don't know how to use "isequal" within a loop and with changing the number of arrays to compare. Here is an adaptation for the code:

```
% Data
>> profiles
    profiles = 

    1x3864 struct array with fields:
    position
    time
    temperature

>> size(years)    % Vector with each profile's time
    3864 1

>> size(position) % Vector with each profile's position
    3864 1

for ii=2000:2012   % Looping over years 2000 to 2012
    year_index=find(years==ii);               % Find profiles within each year
    [C,Ia,Ic]=unique(position(year_index));   % Find unique positions

    if length(Ia)~=length(Ic)                 % If there are repeated values

        for ij=1:length(Ia)                   % Loop over singlets
            repeated_index=year_index(Ic==ij) % Indexes of each position value

            if length(repeated_index)>1       % If it is a repeated value
            % Here is where I want to assess the equality

            if isequal(profiles(repeated_index).temperature)
            profiles(repeated_index(2:end))=NaN;
            end

            % However there aren't enough input arguments, sometimes it will 
            % be just a pair, and sometimes it will be up to 6 different 
            profiles to compare

            end
        end
    end
end
```

So how can I use `isequal` within the loop, without acknowledging how many inputs I will have to use each time? As a tip, `length(repeated_index)` tells us how many each time, but then how to construct a dynamical `isequal` code line?

My goal is to keep just on of each duplicated set, and to keep all of the different profiles for more checks.

Thanks. Feel free to ask for more info or clarifications. 
(Sorry, new to this and not sure how to properly format the code snippet)

Comment: Can you write in pseudocode what it is that you want isequal to do? I find it hard to understand what it is that you are after.

Comment: I added a bit more of code up in the main post. 
These are the added lines:

`if isequal(profiles(repeated_index).temperature);
                profiles(repeated_index(2:end))=NaN;
end`

So basically asses all profiles within the same location and if they are the same data, just keep one of those profiles and remove the rest

Comment: If I understand the question correctly you want to call isequal() with a variable number of input arguments. Is that right?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand, but couldn't you just do something along the lines of `if a == NaN && b == NaN && c == NaN`, namely make a number of separate isequal terms and link them with the `and` operator?

Comment: Ah i think i understand. AFAIK you can't use isequal with a variable number of input elements. Use a loop or vector algebra instead.

Comment: @siliconwafer That is correct.

Comment: @sobek I was trying to avoid yet another loop, or trying to find a more simple and correct way to remove duplicated data. But I am afraid I may have to keep adding loops.
Thanks

Comment: @sobek isequal accepts 2 to N input arguments.

Comment: @CristianFL Then there is no problem, because isequal can be called with 2 inputs, to N inputs.
isequal(1,2,3,4,5,6,4,5,6,7,1,1)

Comment: @siliconwafer The problem is that N changes for every year. Sometimes it is just two profiles, and some times up to 7. I don't know how to build a dynamic code line that changes the number of input arguments, as in:

isequal(1,2,1)             % (for the first year of data)
isequal(3,4)                % (for the second year of data)
isequal(2,5,5,2,3,1)    % (for N-year of data)
etc.

Comment: if repeated_index contains multiple values (is not scalar), then profiles(repeated_index).temperature will return a "comma separated list".  The code as you have it is fine, and can be passed to isequal(). Example:
s(1).a=5
s(2).a=10
s(3).a=0
isequal(s.a) % compares 3 values

Comment: @siliconwafer Now it worked!
I must have been doing something wrong. Every time I tried to use isequal with just one input (such as `s.a`) it would say there weren't enough arguments. Now it works.

Thank you!